# How many positive integers less than a million have either a 2 or a 4 (but not both) in its digits?

Tags: combinatorics, decimal-expansion

I am aware that there are 468559 numbers less than 1,000,000 with 2 as digit as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669737/how-many-positive-integers-1-000-000-contain-the-digit-2), so I assume that means there are also 468559 numbers less than 1,000,000 with 4 as a digit. However, how do you find how many positive integers less than 1,000,000 that have either 2 or 4 as a digit, but not both?

Answer (score 2):

First count the how many numbers there are without any `4`.

Then subtract how many there are without any `2` or `4`.

You have now how many numbers there are with at least one `2` and no `4`.

The same computation will show how many there are with at least one `4` and no `2`.